# Github Actions - Reached heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: javascript, github, npm, github-actions

Github Action gives my this error for the last "run: npm run build"

```
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My workflow file

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: ['master']

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm i
      - run: npm i
        working-directory: client
      - run: npm run build --if-present
        working-directory: client
```

I think this is the solution

```
env:
   NODE_OPTIONS: "--max-old-space-size=4096"
```

But it didn't work yet im not sure i've to add "-" before the env and the exact position of it...
I did it under "run: npm run build --if-present
working-directory: client" but didn't work.

Answer (score 21):

According to [this response](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/70#issuecomment-1191708172) to a similar issue:

`run`

```
jobs:
  make-love:
    steps:
      - name: "Just do it"
        run: |
        export NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096"
        npm start
```

`env`

```
jobs:
  make-love:
    steps:
      - name: "Nothing is impossible"
        env:
          NODE_OPTIONS: "--max_old_space_size=4096"
        run: npm start
```